# show modal on typeahead event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app i have implemented typeahead and has bee splendid so far. I would like one more thing though: When a user selects or autocompletes a suggestion, I want a modal (I'm using bootstrap modal) that has details of the selected item to popup.

#code that implements typeahead

```
}).on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted',
  function(event, data){
    $('.'+event.target.id).val(data.id);
    #Here I would like to call an action in my controller that shows the modal.
  }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You could use `alert()` ... it is modal

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: use `ajax` to call controller method `$.get('ajax/test.html') or $.post()`  read here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I have tried this but has not worked. $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/settings/new",
        dataType: 'script',
        dataToggle: "modal", 
        dataTarget: "#modal-window"
      });